# how to display the live website data in iPhone application

Tags: objective-c, ios6, live-update

I am newbie for iPhone application and I want to create iPhone application based on the website client have. What I want to do is show the **`Upcoming Courses`** from [**this website**](http://smart-kw.com/). Any idea how to do that?

Note that, the table that is there in section `Upcoming Courses` is static data and this site is created using Joomla. The web-developer do the changes in the `Upcoming Courses` section on a weekly basis depending on the courses.

Could anyone suggest me right path what needs to be done?

I also tried to search on google and found that RSS need to be created for that section. So I believe if I need to create RSS, then I would have to store this data in database. Isn't it? Is this only one way to deal with it?

**My Client says, if they do the update in website, it should also get rectified in iPhone application too**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the example right here:

https://github.com/greenisus/cocoa-rss

If you use Joomla, then you have a database already, of course.
I'm pretty sure that there are some sweet modules for RSS, which you can use.

Then you'd just have to parse them in your app.

There is no such thing as **push** in RSS, you'd have to consistently check and update your content.

Comment: so what I believe is I have to create RSS for that... That is basic.. Right?

Comment: @FahimParkar I guess so. Of course there are other ways to parse data out of a website, but RSS is probably the easiest one.